# Is there just one PID for an application and the services it loads

Tags: android, linux

I have an android application that loads three services.  The application itself runs in the background with the three services.  I am wanting to do some CPU usage measures for the application and the three services.  I had placed the code that gathers the metrics that I am using in one of the services.  It occurred to me that the PID that I am getting me only be for the service.  I was hoping someone might know exactly how this works.  Does the application and the three services each have there own PID or is there one PID shared between the application and the services?  If I have not given enough information to answer this question, let me know and I will do what I can to supply more info.

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 0):

> Does the application and the three services each have there own PID or is there one PID shared between the application and the services?

Unless you have taken steps to run them in separate processes (usually not a good idea), these will all run in a single process at any point in time and have a single PID.

That being said:

- Few, if any, Android apps need three services
- Your process can be terminated at any time when you are in the background, and so your PID can and will change over time

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping that this was the case.  We are still in early development and we may not end up using three services.  I have a feeling when all is said and done, everything will be combined into a single service.  I do appreciate your input.

Comment: @user2970381: I can definitely see use cases for two services, where they have substantially different roles and lifespans (e.g., a regular `Service` that runs at user request, plus an `IntentService` for periodic work). Three, though, seems a bit much. :-)